# no data in firebase crashlytics reports after 1 day

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

My iOS app is running firebase reports since several weeks.
I added crashlytics 2 days ago by following the official steps:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=0
in fact, It seems all I had to do was to install these pods:

```
pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.7.2'  
pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.9.3'
```

I also added "DWARF with dSYM File" for the debug information format on both debug and release build settings

Now when I start the app I can see in the log :

```
[Crashlytics] Version 3.9.3 (128)
```

Then I forced a crash from an app launched manually (not with the debugger), and I can see the following in the logs after I restart the app from xcode:
[Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Packaged report with id '9aeb11f6423b4f11b95a0f3263fc7510' for submission
nothing else regarding crashlytics

my question : Why I can't see any data in the firebase crashlytics reports?

Comment: Are you seeing the Crashytics window in your Firebase Console, but it's empty?

Comment: the crashlytics window in firebase only tells me to install the sdk

Comment: it tells me to go there : https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=0

Comment: Crashes forced with `Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()` are handled differently than real crashes (they are buffered and reported after a restart).  If you are using `crash()`, you might try replacing it with some erroneous  code that causes a real crash to see if it shows up in the console.

Comment: @Gogo123 I am having the same problem. I tried several approaches as discussed but none worked.  can you give us more information on the steps you took to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 11):

For those who are still having problems. Check if you still have `pod 'Firebase/Crash'` in your podfile.
My problem was fixed when I removed the old Firebase Crash Reporting.

Answer (score 6):

You're using the right pods for Crashlytics in Firebase - you need both the `Fabric` and `Crashlytics` pods.

Crashes should appear in the Firebase dashboard with the instructions you went through in https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=0. Make sure you also have Firebase Core in your project by following the "Before you begin" steps.

It's possible that your dSYM is missing, which is needed to symbolicate your crashes. Take a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/find-missing-dsym?authuser=0 for instructions on how to upload your dSYM and then try out another test crash.

Also, check out my comment in the other answer for clarifications around Crashlytics in Firebase vs Fabric.

Comment: Hi Alexizamerican! Thanks for your answer. The Crashlytics dashboard magically appeared this morning on my firebase project. Anyway the dashboard is still empty. I was told to upload the dSYMs which I did with the link you gave in a command line: "Successfully submitted symbols for architecture arm64 with UUID". But the dashboard still asks me to upload the dSYMs and it remains empty since then although I made the app crash several times with this dummy code : strcpy(0, "boom");

Comment: I do have Firebase Core in my project and firebase is running well.

Comment: To fully debug this for your specific app it's best to write-in to Firebase support

Answer (score 6):

FYI I had a similar experience, except that my errors started showing up within a few hours. Here are the two sets of instructions I followed, the second of which is actually necessary even though it isn't included in "get started":

1. https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started
2. https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/force-a-crash

The steps I followed, in case you want to go down the list and make sure you didn't miss anything:

1. Add pods to podfile.
2. pod install.
3. Restart xcode.
4. Add build step.
5. Change build settings to DWARF with dSYM File.
6. Add a button that calls Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash().
7. Run the app on simulator, stop the app, restart by clicking it, tap the crash button. Restart the app.
8. Instead of Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash(), call:
   let x: Int? = nil
   let y = 5 + x!
9. Run, stop, click, tap button, crash. Restart.

I'd advise looking at system logs, but it looks like you've already done that. I hope some part of this gives you an idea that helps.

Comment: I tried pretty much every suggested solution without success. The key was running the app **by itself** in the simulator and not from Xcode.

Comment: @gnarlybracket 's comment is the real answer. It deserves 100 votes!

Answer (score 2):

Check run script only when installing
[image]

Comment: why? it's not mentioned anywhere.

Comment: i created an adhoc ipa but dysm are not getting uploaded

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same yesterday, where I crashed the app multiple times. Both with `Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()` and

```
let x: Int? = nil
let y = 5 + x!
```

with no results in the dashboard.

Today I tried implement Firebase Crashlytics in another app. But this time I run it on a device instead of in the simulator. 
And within 5 min. I got data in the dashboard.

So my suggestion is: **Try run it on a real device instead of in the simulator.**

Comment: This made me think, perhaps crashes are logged faster on Firebase once more devices send a crashreport.

Comment: I don't think so. My experience is as long you use a real device, they are coming shortly after you opened the app again